# How to decrease insert query time for 20k rows in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, performance, sql-insert

I have written a query

```
INSERT INTO "public"."users" ("userId", "name", "age")   VALUES     ('1234', 'nop', '11'),....
```

I am trying to insert 20k rows but it is taking like 80+ seconds.
what can be the reason behind this?

Comment: How comes your data to insert? You could use PostgreSQL COPY command and a CSV file to insert data in a faster way. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Comment: data comes from a 3rd party service. Is it normal for pg to take 80+ seconds for 20k lines?

Comment: I mean in which format comes your data or by what means.

Comment: To your question add the answer to; How are you iterating over the 20K rows to form the INSERT statements?

Comment: it is all json. I create a string for the values

```
    const query = users.reduce((acc, user) => {
      acc += `('${user.id}', '${name}', '${age}'),`;
      return acc;
    }, '');
```

Comment: Post your entire loading process to improve your question, so the community could help you.

Comment: **ADD the information as update to question, not in the comments**.  Per @PepeNO show the complete process.

Comment: If your table has no indexes, constraints, or triggers, that is very slow.  If it has any of those things, it might be expected, depending on the details.

Comment: Depends on your data model, available resources and other processes that are consuming resources. It looks very slow to me, but it depends on what is going on: Maybe another proces locked the table for 80 seconds and kept your INSERT waiting all the time.